# Got 404 error when rewrite URL using UrlRewritingNet in IIS 7

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-6, http-status-code-404

I using UrlRewritingNet dll from http://www.urlrewriting.net/ But I got the 404.0 not found error:

```
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070002
```

Here is Handle mapping of StaticFile handler
http://imageshack.us/a/img163/5455/31274006.png

I've configured the same code, web.config with IIS 6 (uncheck Check for file exists) and it works. 
I've tried many ways I get from another posts but it didn't work.
Any tip about this case?

//Since I'm *nix admin so maybe I lack some important points to make a proper question, sorry about that, if you need any info please let me know.
TIA.